# AngularJS ng-repeat + SVG binding Bug in IE10?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, angularjs, svg, cross-browser

I am trying to use AngularJS to populate an SVG. In Firefox and Chrome this works perfectly, however, in IE, I only see the last shape (no matter which shape that is).

HTML:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="300"
    overflow="hidden" ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-cloak>

    <rect fill="white" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="300" />

    <rect ng-repeat="item in items"
        width="{{item.width}}"
        height="{{item.height}}"
        z="{{item.z}}"
        fill="{{item.fill}}"
        transform="translate({{item.tx2}} {{item.ty2}})
            rotate({{item.angle}})
            scale({{item.scaleX}} {{item.scaleY}})
            translate({{item.tx1}} {{item.ty1}})" />

</svg>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('MyModule', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $http, AudioSrv) {

    var demoItem = function (cnt, color) {
        item = {};
        item.x = 0;
        item.y = 0;
        item.width = 100;
        item.height = 100;
        item.fill = color;
        item.z = cnt + 1;
        return item;
    };

    var setItem = function (item, angle, scaleX, scaleY, x, y) {
        item.tx1 = -item.width * 0.5;
        item.ty1 = -item.height * 0.5;
        item.angle = angle;
        item.scaleX = scaleX;
        item.scaleY = scaleY;
        item.tx2 = x;
        item.ty2 = y;
        return item;
    };

    $scope.items = [
        setItem(demoItem(0, 'black'), 0, 2, 2, 0, 0),
        setItem(demoItem(1, 'blue'), 0, 1, 1, 0, 0),
        setItem(demoItem(2, 'orange'), 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0, 0),
        setItem(demoItem(3, 'green'), -90, 2, 2, 200, 150),
        setItem(demoItem(4, 'purple'), 45, 0.5, 0.5, 200, 150)
    ];
});
```

Is this a known bug in IE? Are there any workarounds?

**Edit:**

After further investigation, it seems like all the items in the ng-repeat are being replaced with the last one and this also happens outside the SVG, in inputs bound to the same collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're re-using (and therefore, overwriting the previous version each time) the `item` variable because you don't create a newly scoped version of it:

```
var demoItem = function (cnt, color) {
  item = {}; <-- here
  ...
```

Use this instead:

```
var demoItem = function (cnt, color) {
  var item = {};
  ...
```

Comment: Thanks. The fact that it somehow worked on both Firefox and Chrome completely threw me off path.

Comment: @DannyVarod yeah it's rather surprising that it works on FF/Chrome :)